# How can I receive Callback function message from .dll in ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm trying to call .dll function using Ctypes.
I have a trouble that is get a Call-back function values.
If I call the callback function, the function doesn't give a value.
What is the problem in my python code?

```
void __stdcall callbackmessage(int msgT, char* msg, void* data)
typedef void (__stdcall *CALLBACK)(int, char*, void*);
extern "C" _declspec(dllimport) void    __stdcall callbackfunc(CALLBACK callback, void* userdata);
```

```py
import sys, ctypes
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes, POINTER

Load_DLL = WinDLL("test.dll")
sys.stdout = open('stdout.txt', 'w')

CONNECT= 4116
DISCONNECTED = 4113

def callbackmessage(msgT, msg, data):
     if msgT == 4113:
         print (b"disconnected!")
     elif msgT == 4116:
         print ("Connect!!")


CALLBACK = WINFUNCTYPE( c_int, POINTER(c_char), POINTER(c_void_p))

callbackfunc = Load_DLL.callbackfunc
callbackfunc.argtypes = [CALLBACK, c_void_p]
callbackfunc.restype = c_void_p
CALLBACKMESSAGE = CONNECT|DISCONNECTED
messageprocess = CALLBACK(callbackmessage)

callbackfunc(messageprocess, CALLBACKMESSAGE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

I see several problems with the code:

1. *callbackmessage*'s *Python* signature doesn't reflect the real one (from *C*). To correct it, change it to:

   ```py
   CALLBACK = WINFUNCTYPE(None, c_int, POINTER(c_char), c_void_p)  # Adding 1st arg which is the return type; 3rd arg might also be c_char_p
   ```
2. I'm not sure how *callbackfunc* interprets its 2<sup>nd</sup> argument, but placing *CALLBACKMESSAGE* there seems wrong. I'd do it like:

   ```py
   callbackfunc(messageprocess, byref(c_int(CALLBACKMESSAGE)))
   ```
3. Are you sure that (in *C*) *callbackfunc* is `_declspec(dllimport)`? I think it should be `__declspec(dllexport)`
4. `callbackfunc.restype = None` (minor). *void* and *void* pointer (*c_void_p*) are **not** the same thing
5. Last but not least: This is a logical error: `CALLBACKMESSAGE = CONNECT | DISCONNECTED` This will yield a value of ***4117***, and if that will be *callbackmessage*'s 1<sup>st</sup> arg, **it won't print anything**. So, pick one value (e.g. `CALLBACKMESSAGE = CONNECT`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my code …! But I have a some question..! I edited like that `callbackfunc.restype = None` (Number 3) and I Printed like that `Print(callbackfunc(messageprocess, byref(c_int(CALLBACKMESSAGE))))`, But The Result is `None`... How can I Print DISCONNECTED = 4113 Message..? I think, If I call `callbackfunc` , dll give a DISCONNECTED = 4113 Message..

Comment: It's number 4. It should print *None* as *callbackfunc* returns *None* (*void*). If you want. If you want to print from inside *callbackmessage*, `CALLBACKMESSAGE = DISCONNECTED`.

Comment: oh...I can't understand your answer perfectly... First _callbackfunc_function return type is None(void) . so I edited like that `callbackfunc.restype = None`. Second I want to receive disconnect message from _callbackmessage_, so I defined `CALLBACKMESSAGE = DISCONNECTED` ... As a result. I printed this _callbackfunc_ function, I received `None`... I want to receive the message from `def callbackmessage`

Comment: I'd suggest to add a `print(msgT, msg, data)` at he beginning of *callbackmessage*.

Comment: Were you able to overcome your problem?